# How can I prevent my video uploaded to youtube from locked as private?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-data-api

After uploading video using youtube api with oauth2 authentication(as Desktop app) and code from
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video which is modified to compatible with python3 changing print function and httplib to http.client, YouTube locked uploaded video as private so no option to change as unlisted or public.

Same video file with same title and same description uploaded via youtube studio in webpage isn't locked and other user can watch it.

Sentence 'For videos that have been locked as private due to upload via an unverified API service, you will not be able to appeal.' from https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7300965?hl=en is suspicious, but I can't exactly understand what that senetence means. Actually, there is appeal button on locked private mark.

I really hope someone can help me... thanks!

Comment: Please read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080239/8327971) to this very question.

Comment: @stvar Then what can i do to my app be approved?

Comment: To get your app approved, you'll have to fill in the [official form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) provided by Google; then you'll have to wait for the response -- which, according to the experience of the users of this forum -- does not necessarily arrive shortly.

Comment: @stvar thank you so much. i will try it

Answer (score 0):

I have encuntered the same problem and after some reading on the web I found this [GitHub](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload/issues/306) page.

Where I found my answer

> Hi YouTube Developer,
>
> We're writing to let you know about upcoming changes to the YouTube API Services that will affect API projects created after July 28, 2020.
>
> All videos uploaded via the
> videos.insert endpoint from unverified API Projects created after this
> date will be restricted to private viewing mode.
>
> To lift this restriction, each project must undergo an audit to verify compliancewith the Terms of Service.
>
> Creators who use an affected project to
> upload video will receive an email explaining that their video is
> locked as private, and that they can avoid the restriction by using an
> official or audited service.
>
> Existing API projects will not be
> affected by this change, but we strongly recommend that all developers
> complete a compliance audit for their projects to ensure continued
> access to the YouTube API Services.