# HDR video (H265/HLG) uploaded through YouTube-data-api does not appear as HDR, but same file uploaded via website does

Tags: youtube-data-api

We are currently testing a new feature that generates HDR (H.265 10-bit, HLG or PG) video, and uploads using the YouTube-v3 data api.  When a file is uploaded via the videos/insert API, it does not show it has having "HD" quality, but if I save the file and upload via the YouTube.com creator website, that same video will show the "HD" quality symbol.  Is this a bug or something I may be missing (couldn't find anything in the API)?

Comment: I suspect that your issue is very much related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080239/8327971): YouTube doesn't seem to process videos uploaded via unverified apps. Can you confirm that your uploading app isn't (yet) approved by Google?

Comment: Thanks for the response.the app is verified, but checked again and realized it was working fine, just doesn’t show HDR indicator in Safari (also doesn’t show anywhere in the editor page, only on the player settings)

Answer (score 0):

Actually rechecked and it’s ok. Just doesn’t show HDR indication in Safari.  Thanks for the response