# Does a project using the videos.insert endpoint need to be verified if it's for internal use only?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-authentication

I tried uploading a video to an internal YouTube channel (with the project set to internal use) using the `Videos.insert` endpoint. It appeared to work just fine. I logged onto the YouTube channel and saw the video listed as public. I set the video to private and everything was still okay. A couple of hours later and the video is now locked as private and the internal account received an email that the project needs to be verified.

Is there any way around verifying the API project? Seems kind of strange to have to get permission from Google to upload videos to internal organizational channels.

Comment: [Indeed there's no way to get around verification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080239/8327971), if wanting to have your uploaded videos not locked.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the answer