# Video uploaded via YouTube API gets automatically blocked and set to private by YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

As stated in the title, if I insert a video via API, it automatically gets blocked and set to private once uploaded.

[image: Screenshot]

If I upload the exact same video manually everything goes through. When I try to appeal, it just says that *Appealing this violation is not available*.

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?

Comment: Duplicated question. See [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080239/8327971).

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to create some kind of private service for their API that doesn't require the verification? I highly doubt that google would approve my current test project for public use since they ask for a lot of things that i don't have in their application form. Around two years ago it used to be possible without verification.

Comment: It's true that this *private locked* behavior is very new. As unfortunate as it is, I know no other option for making videos publicly available, than, either doing that manually (via the Web UI) or getting your app through the verification process.

Comment: I would suggest to fill Google's form and provide `N/A` answers to the questions for which you cannot reply concretely (those could be the questions related to business, if you're only a private individual).

Comment: Alright, I'll try that, thanks again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Youtube Data API makes my videos private on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079139/using-youtube-data-api-makes-my-videos-private-on-upload)