# Youtube API v3 - Insert using internal Oauth consent screen gets locked as private

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube Data API's [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) endpoint using an internal OAuth consent screen since it's just for a console application I'm writing to combine and upload videos I have edited.

Every time I do this the video gets locked as private with an email saying:

> your video has been locked as private. This is because it was
> uploaded to YouTube using a third-party service that hasn't yet been
> through our verification process.

It was my understanding that using an internal consent screen for my application would bypass this issue and the need for verification. Can someone explain to me what "internal" actually means here and how I would use the YouTube API correctly for my needs?

Also the option to verify the application is removed when you select "Internal", yet the issue still persists

Comment: I am running into the same issue . I tried deleting the project and creating a brand new one. The videos upload, but then YouTube sets them to Private with no option to appeal. I am using the python script, "Youtube uploader" on github. It worked fine for a year until just now. Something must have changed on YouTube's policy on 3rd party apps..

Comment: Yeah I'm having the same issue - I can get the uploads to go through but they are then locked private and I can't find any way to get this to work with an internal app

Comment: Did some research and you have to submit your app for verification. Basically need to fill out all the fields on the oauth consent form, then at the end it will ask you to submit it for verification. YouTube makes this whole process very coomplicated and confusing. They don't realize that mom and pop businesses are not corporations that can handle all this complexity.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Using Youtube Data API makes my videos private on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079139/using-youtube-data-api-makes-my-videos-private-on-upload)?

Comment: I don't really understand what the point of an internal app is if you still have to verify. The option is removed when you select internal. Also I've found a bunch of documentation and pages such as this one https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en which state internal should not need verification