# Youtube videos privacy locked on upload

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

A while back I wrote a simple script to upload a single approx. 3 min video each day to YouTube using the API. The videos are uploaded as unlisted to my channel and contain some diagnostic information for a science project. This worked fine for several years.

During the Covid lockdown we stopped producing the videos. As the upload activity stopped google removed my quota. Today I made a new application on the google dashboard to resume operations.

I refreshed all the OAuth information and my script is able to upload the videos again. However, now when they upload, they appear as privacy locked and are therefore not viewable to anyone with the link. See the image below from the YouTube studio.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/REsDe.jpg

The code I am using to do the upload can be found here:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video`.

The restrictions just say terms and policies and there is no further information to tell me what might be wrong. Has anyone had a similar issue? Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [Using Youtube Data API makes my videos private on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080239/8327971).

Comment: I read that, but my understanding is if the videos are not for public consumption then the app does not need to be verified. It seems a bit over the top to verify something that approx 3 people with the link will ever see

Comment: Unfortunately, @James, Google does not differentiate videos. Quote from that answer: *All videos uploaded via the `videos.insert` endpoint from unverified API projects created after **28 July 2020** will be restricted to private viewing mode. To lift this restriction, each project must [undergo an audit](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) to verify compliance with the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service).*

Comment: Indeed, @James, that's quite inauspicious, but that's the way Google imposes it be.

Comment: Apps not for public consumption means that they are part of gsuite, and are for internal use only dont need to be verified.   If its not a gsuite account then it needs to be verified  and videos are private until it is.

Comment: On the other hand, @James, due to your work being subsumed to the realm of Science, I could not possible imagine Google rejecting your project.

Comment: I'll go through the verification process and see what happens. Thanks for the help

Comment: But don't forget, @James, that until your project gets approval, you may well upload videos manually (through YouTube's website); this way your videos wouldn't get locked at all.