# How do I use the Youtube API to upload a video and have the copyright check run?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've largely copied the Python code from Google/Youtube's example here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

to upload videos to my channel. I tested with one video and it uploaded successfully but was forced in to "private" visibility due to Youtube being unable to run the copyright checks they now run on video upload. This is a custom video I made with no music so I'm positive there is not copyright issue. The error specifically noted that the copyright check wasn't run and that was the issue.

After googling a bit I have been unable to find a way to upload a video through the API and have these checks run. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I'd also settle for being able to run the check from the Youtube Studio website after the video has been uploaded as I have not found a way to do that either.

Thanks to anyone who has some ideas!

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [Using Youtube Data API makes my videos private on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080239/8327971).

Comment: @stvar this question is related to the [YouTube Copyright check](https://s23527.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/youtube-checks.jpg.optimal.jpg) performed when you upload a video, i'm not sure its a generic not verified issue.

Comment: @dave3250 has your application been verified yet?, How do you know its private because it cant run the copyright check?

Comment: @DaImTo: You may well be right; let's wait to see what the OP responds to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I've shared a image with the text I see in YoutubeStudio about "couldn't run checks" here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oFPZBQgQvMOZqibtYhVqNBQwpXzqm9-S/view?usp=sharing
I could be wrong but I assumed that message referred to the copyright checks. Although weirdly today it seems to have let my video maintain its unlisted privacy settings instead of them being force in to private like my video yesterday.

I will also add that I did not catch the part where I have to have my application verified so that may be it as well. I'll see about getting it verified.

Comment: It looks like my test video today uploaded successfully and it just takes an hour or so to run the checks. It also didn't force the privacy setting on me this time. So I'm no longer sure what my problem was.  My original uploaded video is still forced to private status but the warning about checks is gone. I don't think I have the issue anymore at this time. Thank you a ton for the links and quick answers @stvar and DalmTo (I can't @ 2 ppl).
If there is something I can do to vote up your comments please let me know. I'm new to this site and don't seem to be able to upvote your comments yet.