# Uploaded youtube video is private [Ruby]

Tags: ruby, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload videos to Youtube using `videos.insert`. But unable to upload it as public video. I'm using `Google::Apis::YoutubeV3::YouTubeService` of ruby.

Usecase: Every product added in our platform, it's preview should be uploaded to youtube in our own channel.

We've setup OAuth Consent screen, then we created credentials for Desktop.

1. We've workspace account with support@example.com email
2. Google Cloud account under same email
3. YouTube account with the same email set as owner

Still I cannot upload video as public. We've tried to make it `INTERNAL` too, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [Using Youtube Data API makes my videos private on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080239/8327971).

Comment: So in short, it sounds like [you need to get verified](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form). I can't confirm if that actually fixed your issue, because I haven't done it myself. I'm just reading the documentation, and copying the key link here.