# How to solve the problem that YouTube Data API set my video to private

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

I'm using YouTube Data API to upload videos to my YouTube account.

But when uploading is done, the status were become private.

I know my API has to verified by Google developers console.

After I tried, I realize my free version of WordPress website can't use:

1. Filezilla to connect WordPress website, cause free version doesn't support ftp;
2. plugins.

I hope you can tell what should I do without any website that I can verified by Google developers console.

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [Using Youtube Data API makes my videos private on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080239/8327971).

Comment: but how do i verified the app without any website i can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation [videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

> All videos uploaded via the videos.insert endpoint from unverified API projects created after 28 July 2020 will be restricted to private viewing mode. To lift this restriction, each API project must [undergo an audit](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) to verify compliance with the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service). Please see the API Revision History for more details.

All this means is that you need to go to [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) for your project under the consent screen change the project to production and click the prepare for varication button

[image]

This has nothing to do with WordPress.  This has to do with your project on google developer console.

Comment: but i don't have any website that can be verified.

Comment: This again has nothing to do with your website.  It has to do with your Project on google cloud console.   The place where you created the client id and client secrete for your application.    If you want to be able to upload videos that will be set to public using the API you need to have your application verified.  There is no way around it.

Comment: This video might help you understand the verification process.  [What you need to know about application verification](https://youtu.be/lzIuNmNX9N8)  Again if you want to upload public videos it has to be verified there is no way around it.

Comment: first i want to thank your time. i know has to do with your Project on google cloud console, but when i chose "Prepare for verification" it called me to give a Application home page and privacy policy link. i don't have both of these

Comment: Then you will need to register a domain so that you have a place to put up your application home page and privacy policy links.   This is how it works.  You cant verify your application without it

Comment: ok i got it. i just want to know is there any free ways to do this verification

Comment: Well google doesn't charge you anything for it, well not this API anyway.  So it is free.   Google just requires that you have a place to host the required policies for your users and that that site be registered.

Comment: but register a domain is not free