# How come my video gets locked as private when using the resumable upload api? (youtube)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Around April 2021 I uploaded this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmTTrrO0gj8
Recently, I helped someone do this same here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iY7LaiMRc38&ab_channel=Zizyo

However, I tried to upload another video. This time it got locked as PRIVATE.
Then I found this:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert
It said:

> All videos uploaded via the videos.insert endpoint from unverified API projects created after 28 July 2020 will be restricted to private viewing mode. To lift this restriction, each API project must undergo an audit to verify compliance with the Terms of Service. Please see the API Revision History for more details.

I don't understand. Both my video and the video I helped someone to upload were uploaded after this restriction was enforced. How was I able to upload a video this way, and now I can't?

EDIT: I am asking how I was ABLE to upload the video, I already know there is this restriction. I was able to upload the video after the restriction was enforced, how can I do it again?

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [Using Youtube Data API makes my videos private on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080239/8327971).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question though